# How to check max from range in cursor?

Tags: sql, oracle, max, analytic-functions

I have a problem with transferring an Excel formula to SQL. My excel formula is: `=IF(P2<(MAX($P$2:P2));"Move";"")`.
The P column in excel is a sequence of numbers.

```
a | b 
------
1   
2   
7   
3   MOVE
4   MOVE
8   
9
5   MOVE
10
```

You can find more example on this screenshot:

[image: Excel screenshot]

I created a cursor with a loop but I don't know how to check max from range.
For example when I iterate for fourth row, I have to check max from 1-4 row etc.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a cursor and a loop. Assuming that you have a column that defines the ordering of the rows (say,  `id`), you can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
    case when a < max(a) over(order by id) then 'MOVE' end as b
from mytable t
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `MAX()` Analytic function . But in any case, you'd have an extra column such as `id` for ordering in order to determine the max value for the current row from the first row, since SQL statements represent unordered sets. If you have that `id` column with values ordered as in your sample data, then consider using

```
WITH t2 AS
(
SELECT MAX(a) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN
                                UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                AND
                                CURRENT ROW) AS max_upto_this_row, 
       t.*
  FROM t
)
SELECT a, CASE WHEN max_upto_this_row > a THEN 'Move' END AS b
  FROM t2
 ORDER BY id;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5b0387086193d61e31492762f9634795)</kbd>